# Mongoose Aggregate Query Returns Empty Result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am having a strange problem with Mongoose. I have a record which contains an integer array. I am trying to summarize that array *(it's name is counts)* and run a ranged query between two values. For example we have some records such as;

[0,30,20]  
[10,40,50] 
[0,3,5]

When I want to find which arrays are between 0-50, I need to get 
[0,30,20]  
 [0,3,5]

Now let me explain the strange thing. I am using compass to see all data with a GUI. I wrote necessary query in it and result is just as i expected.

[image: GUI]

## NODEJS CODE

```
findByRange(min, max) {
        console.log(min);
        console.log(max)
        return RecordDBModel.aggregate([
            {
                $project: {
                    sum: { $sum: '$counts' }
                }
            },
            {
                $match: {
                    sum: { $gt: min, $lt: max }
                }
            }
        ], function(err,result){
            if(err){
                console.log(err)
            }
            console.log(result)
        });
    };
```

## SCHEMA

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let RecordSchema = new Schema({
    key: String,
    createdAt: Date,
    counts: [Number],
    value: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Record', RecordSchema);
```

When I give the same inputs in max and min, I am having empty response. What am i doing wrong?

**IMPORTANT** : When I put min and max hardcoded, code works. Im confused a lot

Thanks

Comment: Can you just check the typeof min and max, it may happen when your parameters are not in integer

Comment: OMG THEY ARE STRING BUT HOW

Comment: maybe your API object passing it with `" "`, if not, check your code correctly.

Comment: Thanks yeah you are right. I am so happy right now :D